# Double Integral with Residues

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I'm trying to solve the integral

$$\int_a^b\int_a^b\frac{dxdy}{1+\left(x^2+y^2\right)^\alpha}$$

where the constant $\alpha$ is real-valued and in the range $\alpha\in[1/2,\infty)$.  The bounds $a$ and $b$ lie along the real axis but we cannot make any arguments regarding symmetry about the origin.

My first idea was to do the integral over $x$ first, for instance, and use a contour integral using the poles

$$x_\pm=\pm\left[\left(-1\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha}-\beta\right]^\frac{1}{2}$$

Here I've taken $\beta\equiv y^2$ for convenience and we can say $\beta$ is real-valued and lies in the range $\beta\in[0,\infty)$.

My first question is this:  How would one draw these poles in the complex plane? And how many are there?

Second, what would the contour look like?  My initial thought was a keyhole contour, but the interval is not semi-infinite (unfortunately) - and my second thought was perhaps a dumbbell contour.  It appears there might be branch cuts depending on the value of $\alpha$...

Does anyone dare take on this ugly problem?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Does it have to be done using complex analysis? Why not use polar coordinates?

Comment: I don't get why the residue theorem or complex analysis should work here, since the integration domain is a square.

Comment: Tight approximations are more willing to come from probabilistic arguments: if $X,Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed over $[a,b]$, we may compute the density function of $X^2+Y^2$ and use that to approximate the original integral.

Comment: @Mattos It doesn't need to be solved using complex analysis, it's just a guess.  As for polar coordinates, it's difficult since the region is not spherically symmetric.  I'd like to extend this problem to 3 dimensions, but I'm trying to solve in 2-d first.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Unfortunately I'm looking for an exact solution rather than an approximation - otherwise I'd just solve this numerically to begin with.

Comment: Good luck with that. The distribution of $X^2+Y^2$ is not so nice.

Comment: Does Mathematica or another CAS show a closed form for this integral?